# How can I customize the region of a Firebase Cloud Function written in Python?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to customize the region of a Firebase Cloud Function. I've searched the internet and found many solutions for Firebase Cloud Functions written in Node.js, but not for Firebase Cloud Functions written in Python.

In Node.js, you can use `.region('region')` before your Cloud Functions code. Can this functionality also be utilized in Python? Alternatively, is there an alternative approach to achieve this in Python? Can the region be customized using specific commands?

> Note that I'm using Firebase Cloud Functions, **NOT** Google Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to set the region for your Firebase Cloud Functions written in Python like so:

```py
from firebase_functions import https_fn

@https_fn.on_request(region='asia-east1')
def on_request_example(req: https_fn.Request) -> https_fn.Response:
    return https_fn.Response("Hello world!")
```

I’m using this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions?gen=2nd#keep_a_minimum_number_of_instances_warm) as reference for setting the runtime options of functions, though it does not look like there is currently a specific sample snippet for setting the region for Firebase Cloud Functions written in Python.